# Training 4 models in parallel with 2 cores each slower than training sklearn models iteratively with 8 cores

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, joblib

Let's say I have a simple way to train a model with N cores:

```
def train(cores = 1):
    reg = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=cores).fit(X, y)
    return reg
```

and a simple dataset:

```
X = np.random.random(size=[25_000, 10])
y = np.sum(X, axis = 1)
```

Training on 2 cores takes 7.6 seconds, and on 8 cores takes 3.4 seconds. So as expected when I train a model 4 times with 8 cores it takes 13.6 seconds:

```
models = []
for i in range(4):
    models.append(train(8))
```

However when I try to train them concurrently using ProcessPoolExecutor it takes 14.2 seconds (of which 0.2 seconds are the job submission time):

```
start = time()
models = []
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for i in range(4):
        models.append(executor.submit(train, 2))
    print("Submission Time:", time() - start)
print(time() - start)
```

I understand there are overheads and I could potentially try using joblib or some other way to parallelize models. However I expect that if it takes 7.6 seconds on 2 cores, then training 4 on 4 workers (on a machine with 8 cores) would take less than 10 seconds, not 14 seconds.

Is the slow-down really due to processing overhead? Or is there some oversubscription I'm not noticing? Or is it perhaps possible that the models are attempting to utilize the same cores (I used htop and it seems to max out all cores). I'm not quite sure what's going on here and how to remedy it or best train models in parallel. The goal is to train on machines with up to 100+ cores and up to 100+ models in parallel, this won't function with slowdowns of this scale.

Note I also tried joblib which took 14 seconds as well:

```
start = time()
result = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(train)(2) for _ in range(4))
print(time() - start)
```

EDIT Here is another full script this time 16 models either 1 model per core or 8 cores per model sequentially:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time, sleep
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

X = np.random.random(size=[25_000, 10])
y = np.sum(X, axis=1)


def train(cores=1):
    reg = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=cores).fit(X, y)
    return reg


start = time()
models = []
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    for i in range(16):
        models.append(executor.submit(train, 1))
    print("Submission Time:", time() - start)
print(time() - start)

start = time()
models = []
for i in range(16):
    models.append(train(8))
print(time() - start)
```

Further EDIT:

I have also tried the loky joblib backend:

```
from joblib import parallel_backend, Parallel, delayed

start = time()
with parallel_backend("loky", n_jobs=4):
    Parallel()(delayed(train)(2, X.copy(), y.copy()) for _ in range(8))
print("joblib loky 8 Models:", time() - start)
```

Comment: size=[25000, 10] ?

Comment: The random dataset I generated is of size 25,000 rows and 10 columns.

Comment: And how do you run the code?

Comment: I'm currently running it on ipython, not sure what you mean exactly. I can run it anywhere.

Comment: That's the point. Python's multiple processes can't run interactively.

Comment: I also tried running it in a python script and calling it (python multicore.py). I'm using Ubuntu WSL2

Comment: added some code you can try out

Comment: I don't know what you mean. When I run individual processes I only assign 1 core to each model.

Comment: The time is the same because it's all 8 core tasks, and the amount of work is the same.If you use more cores, the time is different.

Answer (score 0):

To split work, there is some dead weight time lost for setting up separate python processes. I am astonished the parallel penalty is not higher.  If your work only takes 14 seconds,  you won't see benefits of embarrassingly parallel computing.

Another point is that your cores are probably over subscribed. We notice that the sklearn tools often call libraries the do multi processing. When you use joblib, these demands conflict.

Maybe the sklearn parallel_backend is correct tool for you. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.parallel_backend.html